# How do I fix UDP hole punching not working in my program?

Tags: python, networking, udp, hole-punching

I've been trying to test UDP hole punching in Python and it seems that the message is not received by the other client.

Is there a possible solution to this?

Here is the code:

```
from socket import *
from _thread import start_new_thread

from sys import argv

from time import sleep

PORT = 50000 + int(argv[1])

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", PORT))

def read():
    while True:
        print(sock.recvfrom(1024))

start_new_thread(read, ())

while True:
    sock.sendto(b"0", ("<my ip>", [50002, 50001][PORT-50001]))
    sleep(1)
```

Both are on the same network, as I do not own multiple networks to test, but are attempting to communicate through the public IP, but they do not seem to actually receive the message. I expected to receive messages and establish a hole punch, but it does not seem like that is working.

Comment: *"Both are on the same network, as I do not own multiple networks to test, but are attempting to communicate through the public IP"* - make sure your router actually supports [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning) since otherwise this cannot work - no matter what code you write.